# Controlling Docker from a Golang-Webserver

Tags: docker, go

I am looking for a way to control my docker-containers on a server from a golang-webserver. So far i found "github.com/docker/docker/client" and "docker.io/go-docker". both do the same thing i guess, but neither of them have a decent documentation nor examples to work with. Does someone have any experience with those libs?

Comment: The `github.com/docker/docker/client` library seems to have pretty decent docs with some examples. Is there a specific problem you are having?

Comment: i dont understand the differences between the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/client docs looks good to me. For some more example use can look at my project https://github.com/loqutus/rws/blob/master/server/server.go